# A Content Type with custom fields

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

How would you suggest approach this using Drupal 7?

I'd like to create a 'Video' content type with the usual videos fields but I would also like each individual video content type to have many images attached, with each image having fields of it's own.

Basically, each content type would require one video and many images, with fields relevant for each image.

I've looked for duplicate questions and can't see anything that fits but if you know of something please point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Field Collection is a good option if the images will not be re-used across multiple Video content types. If you need to re-use the Images (and their field values) across multiple Video nodes, another option is to create a separate "Image" content type and use the [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to link the Image nodes to the relevant Video nodes.

Comment: This handled my problem perfectly. Cheers Sheena!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module might help you out.